# Is my code running jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, legacy-code

The codebase I've inherited is full of `$()` methods and `$.()` methods.

eg.

```
$("#buttona").show();

$("#buttonb").show();
```

or

```
bComment = $.trim($("#aComment" + i).val().replace(/"/g, "'").replace(/\,/g, " ").replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">"));
```

Which leads me to believe that this is jQuery.

For example that trim method, appears to be a [jquery method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) (takes a string as a parameter) rather than a [core javascript method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679971%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

**However,** I can't see any reference to the jQuery source in the code base. I did a search for 'jquery' over the entire codebase, and couldn't find any `src = jquery...js` references- as said is necessary [here.](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

How is it that this code could be otherwise running jQuery?

Comment: in your browser console try `$.fn.jquery` or `jQuery.fn.jquery`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks Arun, so it returns `"1.6.4"` so yes apparently... perhaps the jquery.js has been renamed something?

Comment: One possibility is that some other JavaScript is dynamically loading jQuery (by dynamically generating an appropriate `script` tag). You should be able to confirm this by looking at the actual document structure in your browser's developer tools (e.g. the Elements tab of Chrome's developer tools) - if this is indeed the case, a `script` tag referencing jQuery may show up, even if it isn't in the original HTML source.

Comment: A suggestion if you want to track down where your jQuery is being loaded from: stick a breakpoint on a call to jQuery (e.g. on `$("#buttona").show();`) and then follow the execution into the function - this should tell you which file the function is defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this one, since Arun P Johny isn't answering.

Yes you are right. That's jquery.

You can check for its version by doing `$.fn.jquery` or `jQuery.fn.jquery`. This will return version.

The reason you didn't see a `src = jquery..js` might be because the script references may have been dynamically assigned. You can see which scripts were actually referenced by looking at the how the script was resolved in your browser (by pressing F12).

But Arun.P.Johny answered it first ;)